# Strange syntax error when attempting to render React from Hypernova-php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, babeljs

I'm receiving the following stack trace that isn't very useful when trying to render a React component using Wayfair's Hypernova php client.

```
  0 => string 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...' (length=33)
  1 => string 'at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)' (length=41)
  2 => string 'at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)' (length=37)
  3 => string 'at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)' (length=44)
  4 => string 'at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/lucasreisch/Documents/brokerfirst/brokerfirst_resources/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)' (length=193)
  5 => string 'at Module.load (module.js:343:32)' (length=33)
  6 => string 'at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)' (length=43)
  7 => string 'at Module.require (module.js:353:17)' (length=36)
  8 => string 'at require (internal/module.js:12:17)' (length=37)
  9 => string 'at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lucasreisch/Documents/brokerfirst/brokerfirst_resources/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/src/index.js:14:1)' (length=148)
  10 => string 'at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)' (length=37)
  11 => string 'at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)' (length=44)
  12 => string 'at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/lucasreisch/Documents/brokerfirst/brokerfirst_resources/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)' (length=193)
  13 => string 'at Module.load (module.js:343:32)' (length=33)
  14 => string 'at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)' (length=43)
  15 => string 'at Module.require (module.js:353:17)' (length=36)
  16 => string 'at require (internal/module.js:12:17)' (length=37)
```

and the component I am rendering is just a barebones react component extending React.component

```
import React from 'react';
import {renderReact} from 'hypernova-react';

class TestSSR extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestSSR
```

I'm assuming this is a Babel issue. My .babelrc file is as follows

```
{
   "presets": ["env", "react"],
   "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "react-css-modules",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Let me know if you've ever seen something like this!!

Luke